# How import jar apache commons cli

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have a project that I need to run, but I can't run it because IntelliJ Idea can't find the apache commons jar.  The issue is importing

```
import org.apache.commons.cli.*;
```

I know the issue is that IntelliJ can't recognize it. I added the jar to my project, but it can't still able to find it.

[image]

I've read in other posts that I would be able to use Maven, but I don't have a pom.xml file available.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add the jar to the classpath and it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot reproduce. After adding JAR file to dependencies and adding an `import` statement on top of the class file everything worked as expected. Maybe try to change `scope`?

Dependencies:
[image]

Class file:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. After I break I realized I was adding the zip and not the jar (face palm). Now everything is good, thank you!